# Is it possible to restrict CoreData entries to a single entity attribute?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is it possible to restrict a Core Data entry to a single attribute? For example, let's say I have this entity:

`Entity`

`Attribute: name`

and there are multiple `Entity` objects that can be added to the database via a `one-to-many` relationship. Can I restrict the data entries so that only `Entity` with different `name` attributes can be added? I don't want to query the data base every time something is added, because that would cause a performance impact when the database gets larger.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

For now I would have the following ideas.

1 - If the attribute is a string, you should make it as a canonical form (a plain text without accents, etc.). Then you can search with predicates like `startsWith` or `endsWith`.

2 - You could add another attribute in entity that you use as a hash value. That hash will be generated when you insert a new object. When you insert a new value, you will check against value.

3 - Indexing the attribute to improve performances.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the predicate thing first, it seems the most straightforward. I like the hash idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

Core Date cannot check automatically for duplicate values, so you have to check first
if an object with a given value exists before inserting a new one.

If you have to insert many objects, then it is more efficient to fetch *all* objects having
values from the new list first instead of many fetch requests.

This is described in ["Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".